# .htaccess allow only one certain path from a certain ip

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to allow access only to one particular url, and only from a certain ip (range).

What I tried (and it seemed like it would work but doesn't) is:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/call/this\.php/with/some/parameters url_ok
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=url_ok
Allow from 10.0.0.0/23
Satisfy All
```

The url restrictions works fine, however when i access it from 192.168.0.1 it's still visible, and it shouldn't be.

It does seem like the one  "Deny from All" would not cover both env and ip restrictions, but I found no way to fix it.

Comment: Check your logs, are you sure the apache server sees `192.168.0.1`? And not your *external facing* IP address?

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with mod_rewrite

Comment: I've set "allow from 10.0" specifically dumb so it doesn't have any chance to match my ip. I am 100% sure i'm not on a 10. class. 
From you answer I understand that it should work.
In regard to mod_rewrite, while looking for solutions I've seen some examples that used mod_rewrite + .htaccess that didn't solve it but were close enough, and I wouldn't mind a solution that would involve mod_rewrite.
Thank you for checking it out anyway.

Comment: So what does the apache logs say, it will tell you what IP you are connecting from?

Comment: the access.log says 200 with request from 5.12.x.x   . Had to connect through VPN, so my ip is different now, but still not 10.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how the [`Satisfy All` is interpreted](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy). The problem here is that the `All` means:

> In this case the default behavior (All) is to require that the client passes the address access restriction *and* enters a valid username and password.

So the access restrictions is the `Allow` part of the "all", and the other part is the username/password. Since you aren't using authentication, that part is assumed to be satisfied. Now, the thing with the `Allow` directive is that *they are all OR'ed*, meaning satisfying **any** `Allow` is good enough. Example:

```
Allow from 1.2.3.4
Allow from 2.3.4.5
```

These directives are logically `OR`ed together, since it's impossible to be from `1.2.3.4` *AND* `2.3.4.5` at the same time.

What you want to do is probably actually use mod_rewrite for something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.0\.0\.
RewriteRule ^call/this\.php/with/some/parameters - [L]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

Comment: Explains the issue and works exactly as needed. 10x.